# consecutive occurrence of character

Tags: php, string, function, character

**number of consecutive occurrence of character followed by character**

Ex  input     : **'zzzyyyyxxxwwvzz'**

> expected output : '3z4y3x2w1v2z'

code that i have tried

```
<?php
$str = "zzzyyyyxxxwwvzz";
$strArray = count_chars($str,1);

foreach ($strArray as $key=>$value)
   {
   echo $value.chr($key);
   }
?>
```

> output is : 5z4y3x2w1v

Comment: So what you have tired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function, get all characters in the given string in an array
- Now, using basic looping and conditionals, and storing previous character, you can determine if consecutive or not, and accordingly get the output string generated.

Try the following (explanation in code comments):

```
$input = 'zzzyyyyxxxwwvzz';

// Split full string into array of single characters
$input_chars = str_split($input);

// initialize some temp variables
$prev_char = '';
$consecutive_count = 0;

$output = '';

// Loop over the characters
foreach ($input_chars as $char) {

    // first time initialize the previous character
    if ( empty($prev_char) ) {
        $prev_char = $char;
        $consecutive_count++;
    } elseif ($prev_char === $char) { // current character matches previous character
        $consecutive_count++;
    } else { // not consecutive character
        // add to output string
        $output .= ($consecutive_count . $prev_char);

        // set current char as new previous_char
        $prev_char = $char;
        $consecutive_count = 1;
    }
}

// handle remaining characters
$output .= ($consecutive_count . $prev_char);
echo $output;
```

## [Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/NTVQRV25779)

Comment: output is 3z4y3x2w1v it not counting the last 2 'z'